# Why is the 32 cubes door broken in FEZ?

Tags: fez

I've just collected 32 cubes, so i can open the 32 cubes door. I've also got the message that i can go there, but when i do, the door is broken.

[image: Fez - 32 cubes broken door]

It is in this location on the map:

[image: Fez - 32 cubes broken door location]

When i got inside, it looks like the world is broken. In the room are no other doors. When i climb up there are 2 regular cubes, but nothing more.

Why is the door for 32 cubes broken?

[image: Fez - inside 32 cubes broken door]

Comment: What do you mean by "how is this possible?" What do you want to know?

Comment: Have you tried rotating to see if there are other exits?  It's been a while since I've played Fez so I don't remember this area specifically...

Comment: Or, if there aren't any other exits, have you tried climbing the ivy and platforms?

Comment: When i first came in to the first room, the door just had 32 slots for cubes. Now the door is just broken. I will add a picture of the map where i am

Comment: I don't remember specifically, but the area with the broken door may not actually be the same area as the one with the real 32 cube door.

Comment: @murgatroid99 i want to know why the door for 32 cubes is broken... I will update the question about what's inside that room

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The door you went through is not the real 32-cube door. The map location that contains the real 32-cube door is this:

[image: 32-cube door map]

As you can see, the pattern of room connections in this image is different from what you see in the question.

One relatively obscure thing about the Fez story, such as it is, is that some areas actually represent the same locations as other areas, but at different times. In a sense, the door you went through is the 32-cube door, but in the future, after it has become a ruin.

Comment: As I recall, there are at least 3 different versions of this area, although the third version may be through the 32-cube door.